# Rotation matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, rotation

Note: I posted a similar question on stats.Stackexchange.com : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193723/linear-regression-after-rotation

I'm having the following issue, and I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong.

I have 2 sets of points, in 2 different arrays : vecta and vectb.

Vectb is the result of a rotation and a translation of vecta.

I'm looking to find both the rotation and the translation based on vecta and vectb :

For the translation, it's easy : T = barycenter(vecta) - barycenter(vectb)

where barycenter is a function that gives the barycenter of each set of points.

For the rotation I work with new vectors :

- vecta_=vecta-barycenter(vecta)
- vectb_=vectb-barycenter(vectb)

I do a linear regression on these 2 sets of points and then I rotate the vectb to get a.

But I cannot get why my result is not the one I excepted.

Below is my python code :

```
#center sets of points
vecta=vecta-array(barycentre(vecta))
vectb=vectb-array(barycentre(vectb))

#Linear regression on each set of points
coef1=polyfit(vecta[:,0],vecta[:,1],1)
coef2=polyfit(vectb[:,0],vectb[:,1],1)

#calculating the angle
angle1=atan2(coef1_[0],1)#coef1_[1] is the intercept, equal to 0 
angle2=atan2(coef2_[0],1)
angle=angle1-angle2
```

I tried to retrieve the angle with the same example but with vectb=rotation of vect a

```
#center sets of points
vecta=vecta-array(barycentre(vecta))
angle=pi/6
rotMatrix = array([[cos(angle), -sin(angle)],[sin(angle),  cos(angle)]])
vectb=rotMatrix.dot(vecta.transpose()).transpose()

#Linear regression on each set of points
coef1=polyfit(vecta[:,0],vecta[:,1],1)
coef2=polyfit(vectb[:,0],vectb[:,1],1)

#calculating the angle
angle1=atan2(coef1_[0],1)
angle2=atan2(coef2_[0],1)
angle=angle1-angle2
```

But I don't get pi/6 as expected

the angle I get is much to small, it's like i am missinterpreting the angle mesure I get. Am i doing something wrong in the angle calculation here ?